# SSRS 2008 - Why are certain months returning no results in matrix but results showing in SQL query pane?

Tags: date, parameters, ssrs-2008-r2

I have searched but have been unable to find any other queries like this one.  I have a query with month and year parameters and the counts are summed into a matrix.  Everything works well for months Jan to Sept incl and year 2018 however when I test it with November or December 2018 and January 2019 I am getting results in the query pane but nothing in the matrix (not even zeros).
The where clause in my query is:
(edited 7/2/18 to show updated YYYY)

```
WHERE        (DATEPART(MM, createdon) = @selectedMonth) AND (DATEPART(YYYY, createdon) = @selectedYear) OR
                         (DATEPART(MM, sb_provisionalstatuschangedate) = @selectedMonth) AND (DATEPART(YYYY, sb_provisionalstatuschangedate) = @selectedYear) OR
                         (DATEPART(MM, sb_confirmedstatuschangedate) = @selectedMonth) AND (DATEPART(YYYY, sb_confirmedstatuschangedate) = @selectedYear) OR
                         (sb_status = 3) AND (statecode = 1) AND (DATEPART(MM, sb_eventdate) = @selectedMonth) AND (DATEPART(YYYY, sb_eventdate) = @selectedYear) OR
                         (statecode = 2) AND (DATEPART(MM, actualclosedate) = @selectedMonth) AND (DATEPART(YYYY, actualclosedate) = @selectedYear)
ORDER BY sb_eventdate, BookingName
```

I have set up available values within the @month parameter for months 1 to 12 and within the @year parameter for 2018 to 2022 (inclusive).
[image]

[image]

An example of one of the expressions (first column):

```
=Sum(iiF(DatePart("m", Fields!createdon.Value) = Parameters!selectedMonth.Value And DatePart("yyyy", Fields!createdon.Value) = Parameters!selectedYear.Value, 1, 0))
```

I tested everything for user selection of Jan 2018 and exported the results and counted what the results should be and everything was correct.
[image]

As a lot of my testing had been on the Jan 18 data I also tested all the other months in 2018.  Everything went well until I got to November and December when I get no results - not even zeros.
[image]

This would normally indicate a problem with the data and therefore no results so I ran the query in SQL query pane (inserting a 12 where query shows @Month and 2018 where query shows @year, which I exported and checked - (the top 10 results showing should all be counting in the matrix under 'cancelled').  There are results for all of the columns.  If there had been no results I would still have expected to see zeros.
[image]

Is anyone able to explain why I am getting nothing for Novemebr, December 18 and also for Jan 19?

Comment: If you run that query for the months that work in the report do you see lots of Nulls there too? Null propagation is often a cause of data going missing.

Comment: Yes, there is always nulls in the 2 columns where you can see nulls above. And also in the actualclosedate column. So I don't think that is the issue.

Comment: However there is a much higher percentage of Nulls the closer the month is to the present - I will run a test without any null value rows and see if that works.  Is there a way around the Null issue?

Comment: Possibly, depends, difficult to assess. Could it be a problem when both of those columns are Null? Are older rows less likely to have both set to null?

Comment: Yes older rows are less likely to have null values but there will always be some nulls in some of the rows.  I did a test sample with no nulls whatsoever in the results, which for December 2018 is only 10 rows but should give me numbers against the 'corporate' event type but I am still getting a completely blank grid - just the row and column headers. It is not displaying the numbers (results of the Expressions) and it is also not displaying the Eventtype.

Comment: I have never used 'Available Values' in the parameters before.  Have I done that bit correctly? (although it works up until Sept 2018)

Comment: it's curious that Sept = 9 (only one digit ) and the months that don't work have two digits. Can't think why that could affect things, but worth a quick look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to sort out the problem and it was that another instance of the database had been created which has now become the main database and the one that used to be the main database is now for emergency only - obviously does not hold the same data.  I was querying one instance on the SQL query pane and another instance in visual studio.  I apologise for wasting your time on something that would not have happened if our communications were better.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: in your where clause "DATEPART(YY" amend this to "DATEPART(YYYY"

Comment: thank you but unfortunately that did not work.  The results are still blank.  If it showed zeros I would understand it a bit more but I have results in the data and no numbers in the matrix. I have update the WHERE clause above to reflect this change.

Answer (score 0):

on the 4th line of your query you have :
(DATEPART(MM, sb_eventdate) = 2018)

This should be:
(DATEPART(YYYY, sb_eventdate) = 2018)

Comment: Thank you for the reply, however I did update this in my Edit to show the correct syntax.  But the error in this one column should not have affected the results in the other columns.  The results are still blank.

Comment: I have setup the data in my vs and query and scripts work as expected, could you forward a copy of rdl file to my email address? (which can be accessed via my profile)